# Does rebooting an iOS device always unpair connected Bluetooth peripherals?

Tags: ios, ipad, bluetooth

I am writing an iPad app that connects to wireless Bluetooth printers. We've discovered that when the iPad is rebooted, the printers that were paired and connected when the iPad was on do not automatically reconnect when the iPad reboots.

I'm just trying to determine if this is normal behavior for all devices, or if there is something specific to these devices that is causing them to not reconnect.

Does anyone happen to have a counter-example (Bluetooth headset, keyboard, etc.) that when the iPad is rebooted reconnect automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, no, this isn't OS-wide behavior. It turns out one of the Bluetooth printer models we are supporting does in fact re-pair when the iPad is turned off and back on, so it looks like it's just a limitation of one printer's hardware.

Comment: If you want to name names - models, manufacturers and OS levels - others might find this more useful. It's good already, but could be better.

Comment: The model that reconnects correctly is the Epson TM-P60II. I will refrain from mentioning the other until I hear a response from the company.